# Is `Convert to Objective-C ARC` useless?

Tags: ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

In `XCode` (version `5.1.1` in my case), when you click `Edit/Refactor/Convert to Objective-C ARC`, what exactly is supposed to happen?

My goal here was to convert my old code to use ARC.

I basically set `Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting` to `Yes`, then I did the above to "refactor" my code. It failed and I ended up spending 5 hours commenting out anything with `autorelease`, `retain`, `release` etc... from my code.

When I finally got all that done, I was able to proceed with the `Convert to Objective-C ARC` operation, which ended up telling me that no changes to my code were necessary, which was true because I had done it all manually.

Is it supposed to do what I did manually, but automatically? Why didn't it?

Comment: LOL, it didn't work for you on one project. So therefore it doesn't do anything? I've used it a couple of times and never with a problem. Having said that, I haven't started a project without ARC for the past 3 years. As long as the project compiles and runs all you need to do is hit the "Convert to ARC" button and it will all work.

Comment: You say it didn't work for you. That's frustrating. But it doesn't mean that the feature does nothing. It means that for one project that you have tried it on it didn't work. I don't know why it didn't work. I'm wondering if it's to do with you enabling ARC before doing the conversion? The "Convert to ARC" button is a short way of referring to the menu option that you chose.

Comment: @Fogmeister I actually thought that too, maybe I should've tried converting without enabling ARC manually, it might have done it for me AND converted my code. Who knows...

Comment: I don't think you should've set the `Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting` to `YES` before using the feature. IME, Xcode is bad at refactoring when the code doesn't compile

Comment: You should not have turned on the `Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting` before running the convert to ARC wizard.

Comment: Well, by enabling ARC you will have rendered your project broken. Any use of retain will have stopped the compiler. Therefore you tried to run the conversion on a project that didn't build and run.

Comment: @Fogmeister If you can confirm this to be the case and put what you just said in an answer, I will accept and upvote. Makes sense.

Comment: @PaulG hmm... well, with Xcode 6 I can't even create a project using ARC so it's hard to verify.

Comment: try adding `-fno-objc-arc` in .m classes shown in build settings under compile resource. Add to the files that are causing error.

Comment: Can someone please explain to me how my question is opinion based? Also, this could help others who have done the same thing, why close it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By turning "Automatic Reference Counting" on manually you told the compiler that the project was already using ARC. Therefore, conversion did nothing - you told the compiler it was already converted.

Obviously all the non-ARC features you used were now errors and you had to fix them.

The normal method is that you do *not* change to Automatic Reference counting. The compiler will then check out your code, make sure that it can convert everything (it won't convert your code if the static analyser finds reference counting bugs, or when things are too complicated), you fix all the things that it refuses to convert, and once everything is Ok you convert everything.

And the answer to your question is "NO".